# Vuex persisted state not storing file from file input

Tags: vue.js, file, vuex

I have a vue.js application where I'm attempting to store files from a file input into a vuex state store. This works just fine - if I `console.log()` the file:

[image]

My vuex state store uses `vuex-persistedstate` to persist the store on a page refresh by storing it in the browser local storage. The attachments/files in the state store however are not stored correctly:

[image]

This means that if I `console.log` the file in the state store, I get an empty object:

[image]

I'm sure root cause of this is probably that the browser does not expose the full file path in the client's file system - probably for security reasons.

Is there a logical way to handle this situation? I assume the object is a link to the file in the client's file system - which could cause issues if the actual file is moved or deleted. I surely don't want to store a blob - the max file size I allow in the file-upload is 10 mb and I allow multiple files.

Comment: The root cause is that a state is persisted in local storage as JSON, and you can't expect it to be restored to proper file object. This is the reason why vuex state is primarily plain  arrays and objects. It's unknown what's the alternative, it depends on your case

Comment: Try to stringify it before save and then parse it. Mutation/getter